# different result between c+ set and unordered_set

Tags: c++, set, unordered

I am working on leetcode Frog Jump question and find some wired result when I use unordered_set instead of set for the following test case. unordered_set and set both have size 4, but looks like unordered_set doesn't loop through all elements.

[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
output :
set size 4
1
2
3
4
unordered set size: 4
1

Struggleing for hours but can't find out any reason. Any tips would be really appeciated.

```
bool canCross(vector<int>& stones) {
    unordered_map<int, set<int>> dp;
    unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> dp1;
    unordered_set<int> s(stones.begin(), stones.end());
    dp[0].insert(0);
    dp1[0].insert(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < stones.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == 10) cout << "set size " << dp[stones[i]].size() << endl;
        for (auto a: dp[stones[i]]) {
            if (i == 10) cout << a << "\t" << endl;
            int b = stones[i];
            if (s.count(b + a - 1)) {
                dp[b + a - 1].insert(a - 1);   
            }
            if (s.count(b + a)) {
                dp[b + a].insert(a);  
            } 
            if (s.count(b + a + 1)) {
                dp[b + a + 1].insert(a + 1);  
            } 
        }

        if (i == 10) cout << "unordered set size: " << dp1[stones[i]].size() << endl;
        for (auto a: dp1[stones[i]]) {
            if (i == 10) cout << a << "\t" << endl;
            int b = stones[i];
            if (s.count(b + a - 1)) {
                dp1[b + a - 1].insert(a - 1);   
            }
            if (s.count(b + a)) {
                dp1[b + a].insert(a);  
            } 
            if (s.count(b + a + 1)) {
                dp1[b + a + 1].insert(a + 1);  
            } 
        }
    }

    return !dp[stones.back()].empty();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because some of your insertions modify the same container that you are currently iterating over by a `for` cycle. Not surprisingly, insertions into `set`and into `unordered_set` might end up in different positions in the linear sequence of container elements. In one container the new element ends up *in front* of the current position and is later iterated over by the cycle. In other container the new element ends up *behind* the current position and is never seen by the cycle.

It is generally not a good idea to modify container that you are currently iterating over by a range-based `for` cycle. It might not produce any undefined behavior in your case (if you are using associative containers with stable iterators), but still... in my opinion range-based `for` should be reserved for iterating over non-changing containers.

In your case insertion of a new element into an `std::unordered_set` may trigger [*rehashing*](http://eel.is/c++draft/unord.req#9) and invalidate all iterators of that `unordered_set`. It means that if that `unordered_set` is currently being iterated over by a range-based `for`, you end up with undefined behavior.